# Is the phrase " Life is so beautiful not to be happy with it" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Can "not to be" used as a sort of conjunction and what would be its grammatical name in any case?

Comment: *not to be* is fine, but "so beautiful" doesn't really make sense here.  A more fluent phrasing would be "Life is **too** beautiful not to be..."

Comment: Besides what @stangdon wrote, here is a somewhat lengthier option that keeps "so": "Life is so beautiful that one can not be unhappy with it."

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't make sense.

It sounds like you're trying to make an argument that one should be happy with life, rather than unhappy, and your using the weight of evidence as the reason.

You should either say:

> Life is **too** beautiful not to be happy.

Or, you could use '*so....that*':

> Life is **so** beautiful **that** you should be happy.